# Two identical code snippets, one of them does not work. How come?

Tags: python

I am trying to rewrite some of my code into functions instead, but a problem has occurred, that does not make any sense for me. I will now show the two code snippets:

Code 1:

```
def get_isPrivateAccount(page_source):
    try:
        match = re.search(r'"isPrivateAccount":(.+?)', page_source)
        if match:
            isPrivateAccount = match.group(1)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print('Could not find the isPrivateAccount of the user. The following exception was raised:\n', e)

    return isPrivateAccount
```

Code 2:

```
page_source = driver.page_source
match = re.search(r'"isPrivateAccount":(.+?)', page_source)

if match:
    is_private = match.group(1)
else:
    print('Match not found')
```

The first code gets the `page_source = driver.page_source` from another function that returns it, exactly the same way written.

How come the second code snippet works perfect and can find '"isPrivateAccount":false' and return 'f' without any problem as a string, but the first code snippet cannot and says that it is 'None'? Error code from first code snippet:
`cannot access local variable 'isPrivateAccount' where it is not associated with a value`

Comment: what happens if `match` is not true but an exception is not raised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error traceback suggests if an exception occurs then the code execution jump to the exception block and then continue till the `return` were `isPrivateAccount`.. but it is only defined if no exception occur.

```
def get_isPrivateAccount(page_source):
    try:
        match = re.search(r'"isPrivateAccount":(.+?)', page_source)
        if match:
            return match.group(1)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print('Could not find the isPrivateAccount of the user. The following exception was raised:\n', e)
```

---

Notice that the `try/except` is a bit meaningless, use instead `raise` and/or a custom excpetion.

```
def get_isPrivateAccount(page_source):
    match = re.search(r'"isPrivateAccount":(.+?)', 'bjkasfdjadas')
    if match:
        return match.group(1)

    print(Exception('Could not find the isPrivateAccount of the user. The following exception was raised:'))
    #raise Excpetion(...)
```

Comment: That was a part of the answer, but how come it returns None everytime, when it always should be either false or true?

Comment: every object has also a boolean value `True` or `False`. Then there is _default scheme_ like for an empty iterable will be always `False` (hence the opposite statement would be that every non empty iterable is `True`), for `int`: `0` is `False`, `str`: `''` is `False`, ..., and `None`  is `False`. This can be checked with `print(bool(obj))`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring and initializing `isPrivateAccount` inside the if statement. If there is no match, the variable will never be defined and the return statement throws an error as you cannot access a variable which does not exist.

You have to define the variable at the top of your function:

```py
isPrivateAccount = None
```